# tensorflow optimization in deeplearning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am a student learning keras.

I was studying about Tensorflow recently,

I am stuck in the problem of not being able to optimize as follows.
(I am running on jupyter notebook)

How can I change the code?
(I wonder how to modify the code to solve the problem of optimization.)

**Imports & Settings**

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

%matplotlib inline

import os, sys
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
from time import time
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
```

```
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))
from utils import MultipleTimeSeriesCV, format_time
```

```
np.random.seed(42)
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
idx = pd.IndexSlice
```

```
DATA_STORE = '../data/assets.h5'
```

```
results_path = Path('results')
if not results_path.exists():
    results_path.mkdir()
    
checkpoint_path = results_path / 'logs'
```

**Create a stock return series to predict asset price moves**

````
data = pd.read_hdf('../12_gradient_boosting_machines/data.h5', 'model_data').dropna().sort_index()```
````

```
outcomes = data.filter(like='fwd').columns.tolist()
```

```
lookahead = 1
outcome= f'r{lookahead:02}_fwd'
```

```
X_cv = data.loc[idx[:, :'2017'], :].drop(outcomes, axis=1)
y_cv = data.loc[idx[:, :'2017'], outcome]
```

**Automate model generation**

```
def make_model(dense_layers, activation, dropout):
    '''Creates a multi-layer perceptron model
    
    dense_layers: List of layer sizes; one number per layer
    '''

    model = Sequential()
    for i, layer_size in enumerate(dense_layers, 1):
        if i == 1:
            model.add(Dense(layer_size, input_dim=X_cv.shape[1]))
            model.add(Activation(activation))
        else:
            model.add(Dense(layer_size))
            model.add(Activation(activation))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                  optimizer='Adam')

    return model
```

**Cross-validate multiple configurations with TensorFlow**

```
n_splits = 12
train_period_length=21 * 12 * 4
test_period_length=21 * 3
cv = MultipleTimeSeriesCV(n_splits=n_splits,
                          train_period_length=train_period_length,
                          test_period_length=test_period_length,
                          lookahead=lookahead)
dense_layer_opts = [(16, 8), (32, 16), (32, 32), (64, 32)]
activation_opts = ['tanh']
dropout_opts = [0, .1, .2]
```

```
param_grid = list(product(dense_layer_opts, activation_opts, dropout_opts))
np.random.shuffle(param_grid)
```

```
def get_train_valid_data(X, y, train_idx, test_idx):
    x_train, y_train = X.iloc[train_idx, :], y.iloc[train_idx]
    x_val, y_val = X.iloc[test_idx, :], y.iloc[test_idx]
    return x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val
```

```
ic = []
scaler = StandardScaler()
for params in param_grid:
    dense_layers, activation, dropout = params
    for batch_size in [64, 256]:
        print(dense_layers, activation, dropout, batch_size)
        checkpoint_dir = checkpoint_path / str(dense_layers) / activation / str(dropout) / str(batch_size)
        if not checkpoint_dir.exists():
            checkpoint_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        start = time()
        for fold, (train_idx, test_idx) in enumerate(cv.split(X_cv)):
            # get train & validation data
            x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = get_train_valid_data(X_cv, y_cv, train_idx, test_idx)
            
            # scale features
            x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
            x_val = scaler.transform(x_val)
            
            # set up dataframes to log results
            preds = y_val.to_frame('actual')
            r = pd.DataFrame(index=y_val.groupby(level='date').size().index)
            
            # create model based on validation parameters
            model = make_model(dense_layers, activation, dropout)
            
            # cross-validate for 20 epochs
            for epoch in range(20):            
                model.fit(x_train,
                          y_train,
                          batch_size=batch_size,
                          epochs=1,
                          verbose=0,
                          shuffle=True,
                          validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
                model.save_weights((checkpoint_dir / f'ckpt_{fold}_{epoch}').as_posix())
                preds[epoch] = model.predict(x_val).squeeze()
                r[epoch] = preds.groupby(level='date').apply(lambda x: spearmanr(x.actual, x[epoch])[0]).to_frame(epoch)
                print(format_time(time()-start), f'{fold + 1:02d} | {epoch + 1:02d} | {r[epoch].mean():7.4f} | {r[epoch].median():7.4f}')
            ic.append(r.assign(dense_layers=str(dense_layers), 
                               activation=activation, 
                               dropout=dropout,
                               batch_size=batch_size,
                               fold=fold))       

        t = time()-start
        pd.concat(ic).to_hdf(results_path / 'scores.h5', 'ic_by_day')
```

```
(64, 32) tanh 0 64
00:00:11 01 | 01 |     nan |     nan
00:00:20 01 | 02 |     nan |     nan
00:00:30 01 | 03 |     nan |     nan
00:00:39 01 | 04 |     nan |     nan
00:00:49 01 | 05 |     nan |     nan
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I don't know anything about keras, but sometimes choosing a big batch size produces nan values in the network

Comment: Some conerns in your code: 1) the transformation can be done for all the training dataset in one go, you can do this with the sklearn pipeline, 2) the model training and prediction are within one fold, you shall train them all before you do preodiction, maybe check the keras tutorial for some more ideas? `https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/`